# jQuery keyup not working on latest Chrome/IE/Opera

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, keyup

The idea is to populate the database every time the user enters a string inside a text box. This works in Safari and Firefox but not in IE, Chrome and Opera.

```
$('.inputClass').on('keyup',function(){
            $.ajax({
                        url         : 'update.php',
                        type        : 'post',
                        data        : $('#MyForm').serialize(),
                        cache       : false,
                        success     : function(html) { /*any other stuff*/ }
            });

            return false; 
});
```

In the above code, the database gets updated if Safari and Firefox are used, but not IE, Chrome and Opera. How would I make it work for all the major browsers? I am using jquery version 1.10.2. Thanks.

Edit:
Below is basically how the HTML and PHP look like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Enqs</title>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="MyForm">
        <input type="text" class="inputClass" name="qty" id="qty" size="5" />
    </form>

    <script>
    $(function(){
       $('.inputClass').on('keyup',function(){
           $.ajax({
                    url         : 'update.php',
                    type        : 'post',
                    data        : $('#MyForm').serialize(),
                    cache       : false,
                    success     : function(html) { /*any other stuff*/ }
          });

          return false; 
       });

    }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the update.php file (a simple MySQL update):

```
<?php
    $qty = $_POST["qty"];
    $qpd = "UPDATE tbl_name SET qty='{$qty}' WHERE id='9'";
    @mysql_query($qpd,$GLOBALS["dbconn"]);
?>
```

Comment: be sure that your jquery code is inside document.ready()..

Comment: look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254092/keyup-keydown-keycode-not-working-on-password-fields-in-ie) , may be useful for you

Comment: Works in my chrome http://jsfiddle.net/b51aga98/

Comment: @Kartikeya yes these codes are within the $(function(){ ... });

Comment: @ZeeTee Yes, your codes in jsfiddle works in my Chrome as well. But not my codes which I use to update the database.

Comment: @Farshad Thanks for the link. It didn't work as well.

Comment: @ddz1507 can you put your online url or js fiddle try . your code already works with firefox and chrome [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/my61p5zo/show/)

Comment: @Farshad I have edited my post and included the rest of the codes. They are just a very simple code structure.

Comment: remove the @ at `@mysql_query`, by suppressing error messages you'll never know if something is going wrong, not even in the apache logs.

Comment: @ddz1507 your code works with IE 8 , Firefox 32 , chrome 37 ! online demo http://farshadajdar.com/tests/ajax/